# what do the sql server icons mean?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2008, icons

I'm using SQL Server 2008 Management studio viewing a 2005 server and have just added 2 users.  For some reason they both have slightly different icons and I'm not sure why.

Anyone have a definitive list of the icons and their meaning or a link to microsoft's doc on it as I can't find anything anywhere.

Thanks.

Comment: Perhaps they just have different permissions? Or maybe one is a member of some group(s) and the other is not.

Comment: Can you add an image(s) showing the two icons?

Comment: It's really just that I want to have a list of icons for reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One icon for user account, another icon is for group account.

Answer (score 3):

If the user icon has a red down arrow, it means the associated login is disabled.

Answer (score 0):

Connect permission has been revoked and Connect permission has been denied are both correct. The only way I've found to cause the red arrow is for the user to NOT have connect access to the database.

Source SQL Server QOTD - 2 July 2014 (Andy Warren)